# React.createElement error using ReduxRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, redux

I'm trying to use redux-router in a project, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is my routes definition (partial) :

```
export default function(store) {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      [ALL NESTED ROUTES]
    </Route>
  )
}
```

My routes work well with react-router.

And then my init code (partial) :

```
import ReduxRouter from 'redux-router'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux' 
[...]

const routes = Routes(store);

class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <ReduxRouter>{routes}</ReduxRouter>
                </Provider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I get the following error on the ReduxRouter's createElement :

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).

I get the following error if I just try to write to console :

```
<ReduxRouter>{routes}</ReduxRouter>
```

In the console, I get a `Symbol(react.element)` with correct props (my routes as children), but with type `undefined`

As a consequence, I then get :

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Root`.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was a stupid one. I was just importing ReduxRouter incorrectly.

Correct import is :

```
import { ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router'
```

Thanks to @tomo from Reactiflux for pointing that out !